# Camera not working when using OpenCV (python)

Tags: python, opencv

When I try to use my webcam in OpenCV it just opens a gray box.

Here is a image:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
```

Here is the error message:

```
C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/REDACTED/Desktop/test/test.py
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-ck70ajc5\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

How would I fix this and make my actual webcam show?

Comment: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` *

Answer (score 0):

As @Rashid mentioned, your camera index looks to be incorrect, otherwise code is fine. In case you Camera index is not in sequence you can find them using following code:

```
 import cv2

 def CameraIndexes():
     # Cam indexes limit, that you would like to check? .
     index = 0
     arr = []
     iter_idx = 10
     while iter_idx > 0:
         cap = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
         if cap.read()[0]:
             arr.append(index)
             cap.release()
         index += 1
         iter_idx -= 1
     return arr

 print("\n\nCamera Indexes: ", CameraIndexes())
```